# Left or Right Hand Side of a Polyline

Tags: sql-server-2008, geospatial, computational-geometry

Quite a tricky one this, as the title suggests I need to work our which side of a polyline a point is.

I have done this in the past using angles and fair bit of preprocessing, but unfortunately need a fairly quick solution.

Any one with any clever ideas?

EDIT:

The aim is to calculate which side of a hurricane path a series of locations are.

Comment: Can your problem be stated as http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon problem?

Comment: Unfortunately not, although somethign similar may be a quick and dirty solution if i cant sort something out quite quickly.  Im basically trying to calulate whether a series of locations are to the left or right of a huricane path....

Comment: Aah, hurricane path. I think you might want to mention it in the original question. For a line segment it sounds obvious to me: take the normal vector from the segment, take the vector from the segment midpoint to the point in question, calculate cosine, check if <0 or >0. Then apply reduction for all the segments in polyline. Was that your original solution? If so, was it flawed in any way?

Comment: Pretty similar to the method you suggest.  Calculate the angle of each section of the polyline, then calculate the angle from the location to the centroid of the polyline and compare essentially....

Comment: Ok, the algorithm seems to be linear time wrt the number of segments. You can make it faster by microoptimizations to the code, parallelizing it, as it's a simple map-reduce problem or rewriting in assembly/C.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a table with a structure of the following form

```
| Point_Data |
+------------+
| id   | int |
| lon  | int |
| lat  | int |
```

You could have a stored procedure defined as follows:

```
create procedure getPoints (@lat0 int, @lon0 int, @lat1 int, @lon1 int)
as
    select id, lon, lat
           isLeft = (lat1 - lat0) * (lon - lon0)
                  - (lat - lat0) * (lon1 - lon0)
      from Point_Data
GO
```

Where `isLeft` would be >0 if it is left, 0 if on the line or <0 if to the right of the line. This is taken from [Area of 2D and 3D Triangles and Polygons](http://softsurfer.com/Archive/algorithm_0101/algorithm_0101.htm).

Comment: I should mention that this only tells you if each segment is to the left or right.